# How to update excel cell via SQL by a coordinate?

Tags: excel, sql-update, oledb

Is it possible to update an excel file using this SQL query?

```
UPDATE [My Sheet] SET B40='17'
```

The B40 is the coordinate of that excel file.
Due to the structure of the existing excel file, I cannot use a table column to update. I only have to use coordinates.

When I run this I get this exception below:

```
No value given for one or more required parameters.
```

And my connection string is:

```
@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName +";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;ReadOnly=False;'"
```

There is also a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160275/oledb-with-updating-excel-cells) but I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for Aditya on the comments that helped me realize I was thinking this a bit wrong.

First, my conn string is now:

```
@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;ReadOnly=False;'"
```

And second, the query is now like:

```
UPDATE [My Sheet$B40:B40] SET F1=17
```

I always thought F1 should be THE coordinate I want to update and that's why I failed.

Answer (score 0):

The usual reason for this error is a missing or misspelled value.

First you check, IS there any Typo error or not?

Comment: The query is pretty simple `UPDATE [My Sheet] SET B40='17'`. If the sheet name is wrong, exception says "There is no sheet by that name". And there is definately B40 in that excel file. So there is no misspelling.

Comment: UPDATE ["+sheetName+"$B40:B40] SET F1='17' apply this method then.

Comment: hey You are using, excel 12.0 so please try this -----                          Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=NO;ReadOnly=False;

Comment: Indeed you did!

Comment: Aditya, do you also know how to update MULTIPLE columns with the same coordinate approach? 
Is it like: `UPDATE [My Sheet$B40:B40;C40:C40] SET F1=17, F2='ssff'`

Comment: how many columns you have to update? If its two or three then you can execute it single single(individual)

Comment: objCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Sheet1$A4:A4] SET F1='17'", objConn);
        objCmdSelect.ExecuteNonQuery();
        objCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Sheet1$A5:A5] SET F1='goodby'", objConn); 
        objCmdSelect.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Yes, I found that but every query needs to execute before the next query. It's not efficient. Can't we send 1 single query includes multiple updates? I want to EXECUTE only ONCE. Because, execution costs time.